# How to change BitBucket pipeline name

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I've just started creating my first pipelines on BitBucket, and I don't know how to change the pipeline's name, currently, it's always the last commit's name.

Answer (score 0):

The pipelines names are their very declaration.

```
declarations:
  yaml-anchors:
    - &pipeline
      - step:
          name: Step Name
          script:
            - exit 0
      
pipelines:
  default: *pipeline
  custom:
    foo: *pipeline
    bar: *pipeline
  pull-requests:
    '**': *pipeline
    hotfix/*: *pipeline
  branches:
    main: *pipeline
```

Then, each pipeline will run on a particular commit, because they will be triggered either manually or because of the rules written in the bitbucket-pipelines.yml. The commit message will also show on the pipeline run record, and I doubt there is anything you can do to tamper it.

The commit message only has a prominent place in the pipeline records UI, the actual name is derived from the condition that triggers the pipeline (PR name, branch name, custom: foo/bar, etc).